# Continuous function bigger than some number

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $c\in(a,b)$ with $A=f(c)\neq0$, then $\exists\delta>0$ with $a\leq c-\delta$, $c+\delta \leq b$ and $|f(x)|>|A|/2\qquad \forall x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)$.

Applying the definition of continuity:
$$\forall\epsilon>0\quad\exists\delta>0 : |f(x)-A|<\epsilon \quad\mathrm{when}\quad |x-c|<\delta \qquad \forall x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)$$
$$|f(x)|-|A|\leq|f(x)-A|<\epsilon$$
$$|f(x)|<\epsilon+|A|$$
But I'm stuck here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose $\;\epsilon=\frac{|A|}2\;$, so that there exists $\;\delta>0\;$ s.t.

$$|x-c|<\delta\;\;\implies\;\;\epsilon>|A-f(x)|\ge |A|-|f(x)|\implies \;\text{complete the argument.}$$